# Ten matches on a table

Tags: matches

Ten matches lay on a table and look like this: "XI+I=X". They create a correct equality. What is this equality? (Write it in arabic numeral system in your answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Turn it upside down: 10 = 1 + 9